# Android options menu always closes

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I would like to know how to prevent the menu bar from closing.

```
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {

}
```

When the activity starts, I open the menu and want it to stay open.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot keep the Options Menu open and it will always act that way. But what you can do is create your own custom menu in a layout.xml and set the visibility to GONE. Then, override the onKeyDown() method and listen for presses of the menu key. If it is pressed, the options menu will be set to open/close (VISIBLE/INVISIBLE) depending on its current state. That way, you can control if the options menu will remain open or not even after touch.