# how to keep an options menu always on the screen

Tags: android, options-menu

I need the options menu to be displayed on screen always.. I've written the code to open options menu on the startup of an activity..

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        openOptionsMenu(); 
    };
```

But on clicking on another item on the screen, the menu goes down.. I want the menu to be on screen always.. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why not make what you would want in the option menu part of your layout in the first place?

Comment: This will probably answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015024/android-options-menu-always-close

Comment: You don't need optionsmenu then. You need actionbar.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the options menu always open? I dont think so.. better add a custom menu in your layout.xml and set it to visible/invisible depending up on its current state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
openOptionsMenu();
}
```